# Gcloud mysql read only user

Tags: mysql, gcloud, readonly, sql-grant, sql-revoke

I'd like to have a mysql user in GCloud that has only select rigths, i.e. a read only user, for security reasons.

For the moment, I have created a user and tried to change its rights with the root account using the following code:

```
REVOKE DROP,DELETE ON *.* FROM 'read_account'@'%';
```

But 0 rows are affected:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)
```

Same issue with the GRANT USAGE, which should have remove all the rights, but there is still no change in the read only account.

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'read_account'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)
```

Does GCloud root account allows us to modify other accounts? Or is there another solution to grant specific privileges to DB users?

Comment: What happens if you execute?
`SHOW GRANTS FOR 'read_account'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.drop user 'read_account'@'%';

2.create user 'read_account'@'%' identified by 'password';

3.grant select on *.* to 'read_account'@'%';

4.flush privileges;